# unable to create a back button when navigate from a table view to another

Tags: objective-c, xcode

this is a newbie question.i ve created a grouped tableview .on clicking  the tableview cell it navigates to a new view.but i m unable to create a back button.I even added a navigation bar in the second view of the nib file.but its of no effect..could you guys help me out..below is the screenshot and code of the first view

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.

    if (indexPath.row==0) {
    self.dvController1 = [[FirstView alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController1 animated:YES];
        }

if (indexPath.row==1) {
    self.dvController2 = [[Tab4 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Tab4" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController2 animated:YES];

}


 }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the presented controller add a button with an `IBAction` in it:

```
- (IBAction)back:(id)sender {
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

And make sure that you have a `navigationController` indeed (meaning that your application needs to be navigation oriented, meaning that you need to instantiate the `navigationController` property in the application delegate)

Comment: dat totally worked... but i am facing another problem..in the above screen shot.if i m to click the first row it takes me to a new view containing tabbar items..where each tabbar contains tableview with navigationController..how to programatically add a button ...will update you with the screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

In your second view .put this code in viewDidLoad method

```
         self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title = @"Back";
```

Answer (score -1):

just hide the bar in the viewWillAppear method & unhide the bar in viewWillDisAppear methods of the tableViewController class. By using

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES/NO;
```